# Excel Top 10 Sales People

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that has sales by sales people such that

```
   A      B             C        D
1  ID    Name        Product  Sales($)   
2  1    John Smith   Toaster   250
3  2    Dina Caan    Kettle    450
4  1    John Smith   Kettle    450
5  1    John Smith   Kettle    250
6  2    Dina Caan    Toaster   250
7  3    Peter Hues   TV        5400
8  3    Peter Hues   Radio     480
9  2    Dina Caan    Radio     100
10 4    Ralph Do     TV        890
11 4    Ralph Do     Radio     100
12 5    Ian Poe      Watch     750
13 6    Tina Hood    TV        450 
14 7    Peter Maan   Watch      99
```

I would like a formula based table in F showing top n (say 3) sales people by total sales with headings ID Name TotalSales($)

I can easily do this with a Pivot Table and then filter the top n but in this instance I would like to do it with a formula.

Edit:Removed product from the results table.

Comment: That would be a whopper of a formula. It would first have to aggregate the data, then rank and then filter. You'll probably need a few helper cells to get this done. Why no pivot tables? It's done with a few clicks and no brain gymnastics.

Comment: When the sheet is exported for another system pivot tables break it, so unfortunately no pivot tables.

Comment: There is no point using *Product* in the results table unless you are going to TEXTJOIN (with CHAR(10) delimiter) the various products that make up the *TotalSales($)*. Your proposed task seems ill conceived.

Comment: @Jeeped Yes sorry that should not have been there.

Answer (score 1):

With Excel's new Dynamic array formulas, you can get the result without building a pivot table, but it requires a few helper cells. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in F2 is  `=UNIQUE(B2:B14)` and it is NOT copied down.

The formula in G2 is `=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$14,$B$2:$B$14,UNIQUE(B2:B14))` NOT copied down.

The top three sales people ranked by their total sales can then be derived with the formula in I2, `=INDEX(SORTBY(F2#,G2#,-1),{1;2;3})` also NOT copied down.

Dynamic arrays "spill" as far as the formula requires and referencing the formula cell of a dynamic array will inherit that spill. That means that if there are new sales people next time around, you don't need to update the list of unique names in column F. The formula will do that automatically.

Comment: Any news on when they will release these to the greater public?

Comment: @ScottCraner This page says it went out in Version 1907 (Build 11901.20176) - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Office-365-95c8d81d-08ba-42c1-914f-bca4603e1426 but I have computers with that version that don't have DA.

Answer (score 0):

to get the top sales in order use this array formula:

```
=LARGE(MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($B$2:$B$14,B:B,0)=ROW($B$2:$B$14),SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,$B$2:$B$14)*{1,1})),ROW(1:1))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

To get the ID and name we can then leverage that with another array formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH($I2,SUMIFS($D:$D,$B:$B,$B$2:$B$14),0)+1)
```

Also in need of Ctrl-Shift-Enter then copy over and down.

[image]